# Typescript type narrowing not working when condition is in separate variable

Tags: typescript, type-narrowing

New to typescript here.

I put a condition in a separate variable for readability purposes, and typescript doesn't narrow the value undefined for one of the branches anymore. Like so:

```
  const isAdmin =
    typeof entry.userEmail !== "undefined" &&
    entry.userEmail !== auth.currentUser.email;

  let entryUser;

  if (isAdmin) {
    entryUser = await getUserByEmail(entry.userEmail);
  } else {
    entryUser = auth.currentUser;
  }
```

`entry.userEmail` inside the first branch of the conditional results in a typescript error because `Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'`. If I don't abstract the condition as a variable, everything is fine.

Surely, there is a way to make this work?

I already know I could NOT have the extra variable and that would fix the issue, but I want to know if there is a way to make type narrowing work in a case like this.

Edit:

To clarify, the following code, which is simply getting rid of the `isAdmin` constant, makes typescript happy: In the first block of the conditional, `entry.userEmail` gets narrowed to be of type `string`, instead of `string | undefined`.

```
  let entryUser;

  if (
    typeof entry.userEmail !== "undefined" &&
    entry.userEmail !== auth.currentUser.email
  ) {
    entryUser = await getUserByEmail(entry.userEmail);
  } else {
    entryUser = auth.currentUser;
  }
```

Edit 2: I opted to do the following. Perhaps not the perfect solution, but I believe in this case it is acceptable, since I can know for sure that `entry.userEmail` is going to be a string in the first block of the if condition

```
  const isAdmin =
    typeof entry.userEmail !== "undefined" &&
    entry.userEmail !== auth.currentUser.email;

  let entryUser;

  if (isAdmin) {
    entryUser = await getUserByEmail(entry.userEmail as string);
  } else {
    entryUser = auth.currentUser;
  }
```

Comment: And how about this `(typeof entry.userEmail) !== "undefined"`?

Comment: @Vladimir No, that doesn't make any difference

Comment: Now I get it. I think it's not possible to narrow `entry.userEmail` out of direct compare in if statement. I think only this can help `getUserByEmail(<string>entry.userEmail);`

Comment: @catwith After reading that I get why in my case typescript doesn't narrow down the type, but I'm not good enough with typescript to successfully adapt their solution to my case. I accepted it as an answer, because it does actually provide an answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that checking for the `typeof` something to be not `'undefined'` is not sufficient enough for Typescript to know that it is not actually `undefined`.

What if you change

```
const isAdmin =
    typeof entry.userEmail !== "undefined" &&
    entry.userEmail !== auth.currentUser.email;
```

To be

```
const isAdmin =
    entry.userEmail &&
    entry.userEmail !== auth.currentUser.email;
```

Comment: No, that's not it. I'll update my question to make it clearer, but in short, if I replace the above value for `isAdmin` in the conditional, everything is fine